# Can I dynamically change parent's function name in the child component instance with my settings in data?

Tags: vue.js, components, emit

Beginner looking for help. thank you so much.

Can I dynamically change parent's function name in the child component instance with my settings in data?

it works fine with this: <my-component btntext="TEXT" @emitfn="fn1">

but I need to do this: <my-component btntext="TEXT" @emitfn="emitname"> and Vue gives me error...

here's my code:

```
<div id="root">
    <my-component btntext="TEXT" @emitfn="emitname"></my-component>
</div>

<script>
Vue.component('myComponent', {
    props: ['btntext'],
    template: '<button @click="childFN">{{btntext}}</button>',
    methods: {
        childFN: function(){
            this.$emit("emitfn");
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            emitname: 'fn1'
        }
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    methods: {
        fn1: function(){
            alert('fn1');
        },
        fn2: function(){
            alert('fn2');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you try to call `fn1` OR `fn2` in your parent from your child component?

Comment: yes I do, and I need this child component in many different places and need to do different things, can I achieve that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach a method using `this.$options.methods['methodName']`.

In your case you can use this:

**Parent component**:

```html
<my-component btntext="TEXT" @emitfn="emitfn"></my-component>
```

```js
methods: {
   fn1: function(){
      alert('fn1');
   },
   fn2: function(){
      alert('fn2');
   },
   emitfn(emitname) {
      this.$options.methods[emitname]();
   },
}
```

**Child component**:

```js
methods: {
   childFN: function(){
      this.$emit("emitfn", this.emitname);
   }
},
```

Comment: thanks I tried your code, but still get this error message: 
[Vue warn]: Property or method "emitname" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: Is `emitname` defined in the parent or the child?

Comment: I have edited my answer @Fu-Han Zhang. Could you try that?

Comment: it's in myComponent(child) > data > emitname

Comment: I have edited my answer @Fu-Han Zhang. Could you try that?

Comment: sorry, but there's an another problem. I now include Vuex in my page, and changed my data to this > emitname: this.$store.state.fn. When I alter the value of state.fn, I can't switch to fn2......

Comment: Is it possible that you can post this as a new question with the new-version code?

Comment: OK just a second

Comment: stackoverflow says I can only post once every 90 minutes.... I'll have to wait for 30 minutes...

Comment: Oh I got the answer from other post, just replace data to a computed method, thank you very much anyway.